# good dictionary which support text to speech or real voice pronunciation?

Tags: software-recommendation, mac, software, dictionary

I have just switch to a mac recently. Trying to find some thing equivalent to Babylon on windows but haven't found any.

I wonder if are there any good dictionary software which support real voice pronunciation or at least text-to-speech? Other functions like one-click translation is also necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OSX has a built in speech synthesizer which is quite good if you're looking for English pronunciation.

You can open up the terminal and enter the following command:

```
say "Hello! How are you?"
```

For dictionary I use the Dictionary application which is shipped with your OS as well. You can import multiple dictionary files into it. [Here](http://davidtse916.wordpress.com/2008/01/24/adding-dictionaries-to-the-built-in-dictionary-application-in-leopard/) is a tutorial to do that.

The best part is that you can type <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> to bring up the inline dictionary in cocoa applications. It's really handy.

Comment: however, you have to go to the terminal and type a command whenever you need to hear the pronunciation. In babylon, there is a button that you can click on to hear the pronunciation whenever you lookup a word